# flask socket.io not working on nginx port 443, it is working with 80, but i need to set on 443

Tags: nginx, socket.io, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, flask-socketio

Socket.io is not working on port no 443 , it is working on 80 port . although i have ssl certificate as well. error i receive  is 504 error code.

NGINX Configuration`

```
server {
    listen   80;//worknig
    listen   443; // Not Working
    server_name  localhost;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    error_page  405     =200 $uri;
    #charset koi8-r;

    location ^~ /app/socket.io {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/app/socket.io;     
        }
    location ^~ /app/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/app/;
        rewrite ^/coromandel(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

FrontEnd code:

```
const SOCKET =io.connect(window.location.origin, {path: "/app/socket.io"});
```

Flask code:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app,path="/app/socket.io")
```

Comment: Are your non Socket.IO endpoints working on 443, or are they also broken?

Comment: Non socket.io app is working fine on 443